# mongodb aggregate average of array elements

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have collection of documents in mongodb 2.6.11 where 'cpu' is array showing [cpu0,cpu1], see example below

```
{ cpu: [ '100','20' ], hostname: 'host1',_id: 1 },
{ cpu: [ '40','30' ], hostname: 'host1',_id: 2 }, etc
```

I'm looking for average cpu on 'host1' which is ['70','25'] ( because '100'+'40'/2='70' and '20'+'30'='25' ). I am trying aggregate for cpu1 but it is not giving me right result

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group:
            {
                _id:"hostname",
                avgCPU: {$avg: "$cpu.1"}
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB 2.6 positional notation in aggregation is unsupported, you will need to `$unwind` your document, and on the next stage perform the `$avg`.

In MondoDB 3.2 however, you have the $arrayElemAt operator which return the element at specified index `{ $arrayElemAt: [ <array>, <idx> ] }`

Based on the document structure you posted, this query will do the work:

```
db.cpu.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$cpu"},
{$group: {
   _id: "$_id",
   first: {$first: "$cpu"},
   last: {$last: "$cpu"}
}},
{$group: {
   _id: 0,
   firstAvg: {$avg: "$first"},
   lastAvg: {$avg: "$last"}
}}
]);
```

Comment: sorry, _id are different , I just wanted to simplify

Comment: So like below ? db.collection.aggregate(
    [   {
            $unwind: {
                path: "$cpu",
                includeArrayIndex: "VS"
            }
        },
        {$match: {"VS":{"$eq":1}}},
        {
            $group: {
                _id: "hostname",
                avgCPU: {$avg: "$cpu"}
            }
        }
    ]
);

Comment: I have update my answer with a query that will get the result that you need

Comment: Appreciate, print(JSON.stringify(db.cpu.aggregate(..)) gives me {"_firstBatch":[{"_id":0,"firstAvg":0,"lastAvg":0}],"_cursor":{}} ?