# How do you find aggregate in mongo array with size greater than two?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In the mongo 2.6 document, see few below

```
nms:PRIMARY> db.checkpointstest4.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "cpu" : [ 100, 20, 60 ], "hostname" : "host1" }
{ "_id" : 2, "cpu" : [ 40, 30, 80 ], "hostname" : "host1" }
```

I need to find average cpu (per cpu array index) per hosts I.E based on two above, average for `host1` will be `[70,25,70]` because `cpu[0]` is `100+40=70` etc

I am lost when I have 3 array elements instead of two array elements, see [mongodb aggregate average of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226104/mongodb-aggregate-average-of-array-elements)

Finally below worked for me:

```
var map = function () {
    for (var idx = 0; idx < this.cpu.length; idx++) {
        var mapped = {
            idx: idx,
            val: this.cpu[idx]
        };
        emit(this.hostname, {"cpu": mapped});
    }
};

var reduce = function (key, values) {

    var cpu = []; var sum = [0,0,0]; cnt = [0,0,0];
    values.forEach(function (value) {        
        sum[value.cpu.idx] += value.cpu.val;
        cnt[value.cpu.idx] +=1;       
        cpu[value.cpu.idx] = sum[value.cpu.idx]/cnt[value.cpu.idx]
    });   
    return {"cpu": cpu};
};

db.checkpointstest4.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: "checkpointstest4_result"});
```

Comment: Which mongodb version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, don't have a version that old to test with :-/

Comment: I can upgrade if it is easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading would be your best option as mentioned with the [`includeArrayIndex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#includearrayindex-and-preservenullandemptyarrays) available to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) from MongoDB 3.2 onwards.

If you cannot do that, then you can always process with mapReduce instead:

```js
db.checkpointstest4.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var mapped = this.cpu.map(function(val) {
            return { "val": val, "cnt": 1 };
        });
        emit(this.hostname,{ "cpu": mapped });
    },
    function(key,values) {
        var cpu = [];

        values.forEach(function(value) {
            value.cpu.forEach(function(item,idx) {
                if ( cpu[idx] == undefined )
                    cpu[idx] = { "val": 0, "cnt": 0 };
                cpu[idx].val += item.val;
                cpu[idx].cnt += item.cnt
            });
        });
        return { "cpu": cpu };
    },
    {
        "out": { "inline": 1 },
        "finalize": function(key,value) {
            return { 
                "cpu": value.cpu.map(function(cpu) {
                    return cpu.val / cpu.cnt;
                 })
            };
        }
    }
)
```

So the steps there are in the "mapper" function to transform the array content to be an array of objects containing the "value" from the element and a "count" for later reference as input to the "reduce" function. You need this to be consistent with how the reducer is going to work with this and is necessary to get the overall counts needed to get the average.

In the "reducer" itself you are basically summing the array contents for each position for both the "value" and the "count". This is important as the "reduce" function can be called multiple times in the overall reduction process, feeding it's output as "input" in a subsequent call. So that is why both mapper and reducer are working in this format.

With the final reduced results, the `finalize` function is called to simply look at each summed "value" and "count" and divide by the count to return an average.

Mileage may vary on whether modern aggregation pipeline processing or indeed this mapReduce process will perform the best, mostly depending on the data. Using `$unwind` in the prescribed way will certainly increase the amount of documents to be analyzed and thus produce overhead. On the contrary, while JavaScript processing as opposed to native operators in the aggregation framework will generally be slower, but the document processing overhead here is reduced since this is keeping arrays.

The advice I would give is use this if upgrading to 3.2 is not an option, yet if even an option then at least benchmark the two on your data and expected growth to see which works best for you.

---

Returns

```js
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "host1",
                        "value" : {
                                "cpu" : [
                                        70,
                                        25,
                                        70
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "timeMillis" : 38,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 2,
                "emit" : 2,
                "reduce" : 1,
                "output" : 1
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: got the error below: 2016-02-10T09:05:25.482-0500 map reduce failed:{
        "errmsg" : "exception: TypeError: Property 'cpu' of object [object Object] is not a function near 'ed = this.cpu(function (val) '  (line 2)",
        "code" : 16722,
        "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1224

Comment: reduce function is: function (key, values) {
        var cpu = [];
        values.forEach(function (value) {
            value.cpu.forEach(function(item, idx) {
                if (cpu[idx] == undefined)
                    cpu[idx] = {"val": 0, "cnt": 0};
                cpu[idx].val += item.val;
                cpu[idx].cnt += item.cnt
            });
        });
        return {"cpu": cpu};
    }

Comment: Tried to troubleshoot map function: nms:PRIMARY> db.checkpointstest4.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "cpu" : [ 100, 20, 60 ], "hostname" : "host1" }
{ "_id" : 2, "cpu" : [ 40, 30, 80 ], "hostname" : "host1" }


nms:PRIMARY> emit
function (key, value) {
    print("emit");
    print("key: " + key + "  value: " + tojson(value));
}


nms:PRIMARY> var myDoc = db.checkpointstest4.findOne({_id:1});

nms:PRIMARY> map.apply(myDoc);
2016-02-10T09:58:56.832-0500 TypeError: Property 'cpu' of object [object Object] is not a function

Comment: @irom Must admit I typed this in away from an instance to test on. But there were only three quick and obvious typos that needed to be ammended ( missing `map`, `function` within `forEach` and a reversed bracket `{` ). The answer is still the basic concept of getting sums and counts for each array index in place.

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB 3.2 where `includeArrayIndex` showed up, you can do this;

```
db.test.aggregate(
  {$unwind: {path:"$cpu", includeArrayIndex:"index"}}, 
  {$group: {_id:{h:"$hostname",i:"$index"}, cpu:{$avg:"$cpu"}}}, 
  {$sort:{"_id.i":1}},
  {$group:{_id:"$_id.h", cpu:{$push:"$cpu"}}}
)

// Make a row for each array element with an index field added.
{$unwind: {path:"$cpu", includeArrayIndex:"index"}}, 

// Group by hostname+index, calculate average for each group.
{$group: {_id:{h:"$hostname",i:"$index"}, cpu:{$avg:"$cpu"}}},

// Sort by index (to get the array in the next step sorted correctly)
{$sort:{"_id.i":1}},

// Group by host, pushing the averages into an array in order.
{$group:{_id:"$_id.h", cpu:{$push:"$cpu"}}}
```

Comment: Good to show a usage option for `includeArrayIndex`. But of course it may not always be an immediate option for someone to make the jump to MongoDB 3.2, especially considering their current working version is reported to be 2.6. Not that it wouldn't be advantageous to do so. So good usage example.